# Copy files from remote host to vagrant instance using ansible

Tags: ansible, vagrant, rsync

Similar questions have been asked before, but none have been answered or are specific to Vagrant.

I have a directory on host `master` which I would like to synchronize with my vagrant instance. Here's my playbook:

```
- hosts: master
  vars:
    backup_dir: /var/backups/projects/civi.common.scot/backups/latest/
    dest_dir: /var/import
  tasks:
    - name: Synchronize directories
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ backup_dir }}"
        dest: "{{ dest_dir }}"
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: default
```

Here is my inventory:

```
default ansible_host=192.168.121.199 ansible_port=22  ansible_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='/run/media/daniel/RAIDStore/Workspace/docker/newhume/.vagrant/machines/default/libvirt/private_key'
master ansible_host=hume.common.scot
```

When I run this play, the process does not seem to copy any files to disk, but does not error or quit either.

With `ssh.config.forward_agent = true` in my `Vagrantfile`, I am able to issue the following command from the Vagrant guest:

```
rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' -avz -e ssh $remote_user@$remote_host:$remote_path $local_path`
```

However, the following playbook does *not* work (same problem as when using the `synchronize` module):

```
- name: synchronize directories (bugfix for above)
  command: "rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' -avz -e ssh {{ remote_user }}@{{ remote_host }}:{{ backup_directory }} {{ dest_dir }}"
```

I have also tried using `shell` instead of `command`.

How can I copy these files to my vagrant instance?

Comment: Just to confirm, this is for backup purposes? You don't state as such, but your playbook uses "backup_dir" as a variable. Because you can easily map a folder from your host to your vagrant which will keep it in sync without needing to use ansible.

Comment: Not for backup purposes, no. The idea is to synchronize a development machine's content database with the production master. Since the production system has a backup directory it populates daily and then synchronizes with its own backup systems, it makes sense to use that backup directory as a data store for pulling data into the dev environment. That dev environment *could* be a remote cloud server if the dev works remotely, it *could* be a training system, or it could be a local vagrant host.

Answer (score 1):

The "syschronize" Ansible module "is run and originates on the local host where Ansible is being run" (quote from manpage). So it is for copy from *local* to *remote*. What you want to do, is to copy from *remote A* (master) to *remote B* (default).
To acomplish that you'd have to exchange ssh keys for a specific user from B to A and vice versa for known_hosts. The following should guide you through the process:

```
- hosts: default
  tasks:
    # transfer local pub-key to remote authorized_keys
    - name: fetch local ssh key from root user
      shell: cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
      register: ssh_keys
      changed_when: false
    - name: deploy ssh key to remote server
      authorized_key:
              user: "root"
              key: "{{ item }}"
      delegate_to: "master"
      with_items:
              - "{{ ssh_keys.stdout }}"

    # fetch remote host key and add to local known_hosts
    # to omit key accept prompt
    - name: fetch ssh rsa host key from remote server
      shell: cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
      register: ssh_host_rsa_key
      delegate_to: master
      changed_when: false
    - name: create /root/.ssh/ if not existant
      file:
          path: "/root/.ssh/"
          owner: root
          group: root
          mode: 0700
          state: directory
    - name: add hostkey to root known host file
      lineinfile:
          path: "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
          line: "{{ master.fqdn }} {{ ssh_host_rsa_key.stdout }}"
          mode: 0600
          create: yes
          state: present
      with_items:
          - "{{ ssh_keys.stdout }}"

    # now call rsync to fetch from master
    - name: fetch from remote
      shell: rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' -avz -e ssh root@{{ master.fqdn }}:{{ backup_directory }} {{ dest_dir }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, not sure why it was down-voted. Is there no way to do this through agent forwarding?

Comment: What do you mean by "agent forwarding"? ssh agent? => don't know ; One other way would be downloading to /tmp/, then uploading. But that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Agent forwarding is a feature of the SSH protocol which allows the SSH client on an SSH server to log in to and authenticate with other SSH servers without having to exchange keys with the original client, bypassing the security problem of uploading an SSH key to a remote host in the manner you describe. See here for more details: https://yakking.branchable.com/posts/ssh-A/